# JSON WebMethod not working in Sitefinity

Tags: ajax, web-services, json, asmx, sitefinity

I am trying to call via ajax a WebMethod hosted in a traditional ASP.Net WebForm code-behind page.  Here is the code for the WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public static object States()
{
    StateProvince[] states = new StateProvince[] { };
    ApplicationServiceClient proxy = null;

    try
    {
        proxy = new ApplicationServiceClient();
        states = proxy.GetStateProvinces();
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseServiceProxy(proxy);
    }
    return states;
}
```

The WebMethod works just fine in my stand-alone development environment or if deployed normally to IIS, but when I deploy the aspx page to Sitefinity, I get the following exception when it's called:

**Server Error in '/' Application.**
*Unknown web method States.aspx.*
Parameter name: methodName

I'm not sure if Sitefinity is hijacking the URL and post-pending the ".aspx" or what is going on here.

Here is the jquery call that is calling the web method:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Regions.aspx/States",
        data: "{}",
        success: function(data) {
            // implementation omitted
        },
        error: function(xhr, msg) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

I can replicate the problem by posting the request manually using Fiddler.

Again, this works just fine everywhere except when deployed to Sitefinity.  Anybody have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

What version of .NET is Sitefinity running? Page methods are a recent addition.

Answer (score 0):

use **dataType: "json",**